# How to append children to a list of widget without rebuilding the existing widgets in the list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, rxdart

I am new to flutter and I think I miss understand the Widgets lifecycle and what is feasible. I use Riverpod for state management and Service creation.

### Context

I am building a widget to display a stream of logs coming from a LogManager. It will display an history of logs (currentLogs) and every time a new log is added to the stream, it should display in my Widget.

You can see below that I use SelectableText.rich and TextSpan, the reason is that I style each TextSpan differently depending on the log it represents but I still want to be able to select text across different TextSpan (Styling stuff removed here for readability).

```dart
import 'package:bulo_ui/core/connect/model/server_config.dart';
import 'package:bulo_ui/core/log/model/log.dart';
import 'package:bulo_ui/core/log/providers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class LogStreamWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  final Server? server;
  Stream<Log>? _logStream;
  List<Log> _logs = [];

  LogStreamWidget(this.server);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final logManager = ref.read(logManagerProvider(server));

    // Concatenate existing logs + stream of new logs.
    final currentLogsStream = Stream.fromIterable(logManager.currentLogs);
    _logStream = Rx.concat([currentLogsStream, logManager.newLogStream]);

    _logs = List.from(logManager.currentLogs);
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder<Log>(
        stream: _logStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // Append the new log to the log list
            _logs.add(snapshot.data!);
          }

          return SelectableText.rich(
            TextSpan(
              children: _logs.map((log) {
                return (TextSpan(text: "${log.timeStr} ${log.msg}\n"));
              }).toList(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### The Issue

With the current implementation, my selection of text in the widget is erased every time a new log is added to the stream. That's very annoying / not user friendly, imagine a log every 1s, you finish to select a piece of the logs that you have to do it again.....

### Own investigation

I think this happens because whenever the stream `_logStream` have a new data, the entire SelectableText.rich widget rebuild. So the selected text in the TextSpan widgets disappear and redraw.

I believe I need to find a way to use the stream to APPEND children to a Widget like Column without rebuilding it and its existing children. This does not seems to fit how Flutter and the WidgetTree works, so maybe there is another solution?

**But yeah, basically need to dynamically add widgets / TextSpan to a list already displayed without redrawing the previous TextSpan objects.**

Many thanks to the community for your help!